# e.stopPropagation() - is the clicked element a propagation or the original?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you check whether the element is the original element or a propagation of the clicked element?

---

#### Edit

If I do this, `'propagation'` is always alerted:

```
this.row.click(function(e){
    if(e.target === this) alert('origin');
    else alert('propagation');

    //e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [`event.target` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
if(event.target === this) {
    // origin of the event
}
```

Comment: @clarkk: What is `this.row`? Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. Some elements will never be the origin. E.g. the space of a table row is all consumed by the cells.

Comment: row is a TR.. so thats why :)